# How to use require() with variable names in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have read many solutions on stack overflow and blogs but none could solve my problem.
I have image urls from api. It is uncommon but it is an assignment to me

```
   productsdata= {
        id: 12,
        title: "Cat Tee Black T-Shirt",
        description: "4 MSL",
        availableSizes: ["S", "XS"],
        style: "Black with custom print",
        price: 10.9,
        installments: 9,
        currencyId: "USD",
        currencyFormat: "$",
        isFreeShipping: true,
        src_1: "../../assets/113_1.jpg",
        src_2: "../../assets/113_2.jpg"
      },
```

here I am displaying image as

```
{productsdata.map(product => {
        return (
          <>
            <img src={product.src_1} width="200" height="200" alt="tshirt" />
            {/* <img src={product.src_2} width="200" height="200" /> */}
          </>
        );
      })}
```

but it doesn't work as `require()` only works with static url.
Could someone pls help me?

Comment: Please post your ReactJS code that generates the `<img />` element.

Comment: <img src ={src1} />  Use Curly Braces if you have the api response in the jsx

Comment: How does img path from API can be a relative path? Seems strange.

Comment: Ask them to fix their API response as it makes no sense to send relative URLs in response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the image urls as

```
 productsdata= {

        src_1: "113_1.jpg",
        src_2: "113_2.jpg"
      },
```

and changed the 'src' attribute as

```
 <img src={require(`../../assets/${product.src_1}`)} width="200" height="200" alt="tshirt" />
```

It worked fine. Here also 'require' is using variable and dynamic url. Who on the earth would think of writing this way. I think it's a bug in javascript or I don't have enough understanding:p

Answer (score -1):

you should use like this-

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
    import Products from './old';
 const New = (props) =>{
    
    return(
        <div>
       {Products.map((Product, i)=>(
         Object.values(Product).map((prod, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <p>id: {prod.id}</p>
                <p>category: {prod.category}</p>
                <p>filename: {prod.filename}</p>
                <p>name: {prod.name}</p>
                <p>price: {prod.price}</p>
            </div>
          )) 
       )

       )}
        </div>
    );
}
export default New;
```

Comment: where old.js file will look like this==========>     const Products =  [ {
    "867850": {
        "id": "867850",
        "category": "Clothes",
        "filename": "purse",
        "name": "Purse",
        "price": 45.48
    }}];

    export default Products;

Comment: I did not get it. How could this solve my problem with rendering image

Comment: Use   var  Products =  require('./old') ;  and change Products.map to =>  Products.default.map

Comment: Thanks for your concern but I did not understand what you were saying